# Ubuntu in VMware Player Cannot Access Internet for Updates

Tags: networking, vmware, proxy

I am using VMware Player version 6 to host Ubuntu Desktop 14.04 LTS on my MS Windows 7 Ultimate 32bit. My internet connection is through squid proxy with password authentication.

Since Ubuntu network is using NAT, I set up the networking to use proxy and let it be system wide.  Now I can access internet via browser, but I can't install any other software from Software Center.  Please advice.

Comment: List down the errors when you try to install some application. What happen in fact?

Comment: I just tried update manager, I got the following sample error:

Comment: W:Failed to fetch http://extras.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/precise/main/binary-i386/Packages  407  Proxy Authentication Required

Answer (score 1):

create a file (it doesn't exist by default):

```
sudo gedit /etc/apt/apt.conf.d/01proxy
```

Then add the following: (Replace with yours)

Acquire::http::Proxy  " http://[username]:[password]@[proxy-webaddress]:[port]";

Acquire::https::Proxy  " http://[username]:[password]@[proxy-webaddress]:[port]";

Save the file and then try:

```
sudo apt-get update
```

Comment: I didn't find this file, so I did the following:

Comment: I said this doesn't exist by default

Comment: did that solve your problem?

Comment: I created a file with the same name, I added the text (i think we missed a semi colon after text), then I tried.  The same error show.

Comment: yes there is a semi colon, did you tried with its presence?

Comment: Yes, I did.  Without semicolon, it doesn't work also with different error message.

Comment: I just also tried the following command:export http_proxy=http://username:password@address:port/ no luck also